# Copying and Pasting Microsoft Access Query results using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Very new to PowerShell, but wondering if the below is possible...

I'd like to expand on the below script (which simply opens an AccessDB, runs a quick query and displays its results).

**Can the results of Query1 (which is a simple table) be copied or exported into an Excel document?**

```
$Acc = New-Object –com Access.Application

#Opens the Access Database
$Acc.OpenCurrentDataBase("TEST.mdb")

#Runs the queries
$Acc.DoCmd.OpenQuery("QUERY1")
```

Comment: If you assign the results, ala `$Results = $Acc.DoCmd.OpenQuery("QUERY1")`, then sure.  At that point just manipulate or formulate `$Results` into whatever format you need, then use a `-com Excel.Application` as you please.  You'll need to give more detail as to what specific problem you're having using the Excel COM object, for this to be less broad, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use this sample  to give you a set off:

```
$path = "C:\database.mdb"
$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3

$cn = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
$rs = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset

$cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = $path")

$rs.Open("SELECT TOP 1 [High Jumper Data].[Name], 
  [High Jumper Data].[Personal Best], [High Jumper Data].[Season Best] 
  FROM [High Jumper Data]
  ORDER BY [High Jumper Data].[Personal Best] 
  DESC , [High Jumper Data].[Season Best] DESC", 
  $cn, $adOpenStatic, $adLockOptimistic)

$rs.MoveFirst()

Write-host "The winner will likely be " $rs.Fields.Item("Name").Value
```

You can get more details on :

[microsoft-access-database-with-PS](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/08/13/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-query-a-microsoft-access-database-with-a-windows-powershell-script/)

Some more Guideline with scripts and functions:

[Accessing MS Access DB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.05.scriptingguys.aspx)

Hope it helps.